# jQuery text animation slide-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to use jQuery slide-in animation and it seems to work fine, but my the second animation doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

This line:

```
$('#headline1Txt').animate({'marginLeft': "100px"}, 1000);
```

is working fine, but this one:

```
$("#headline1Txt").animate({left: "+=30"}, 500);
```

is not working.

[My Code](http://jsfiddle.net/H35cY/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="headlineText">
        <p id="headline1Txt" >Striped Bag</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#headline1Txt').animate({'marginLeft': "100px"}, 1000);
    $("#headline1Txt").animate({left: "+=30"}, 500);
});
```

**CSS**

```
#headlineText {
     margin: 60px 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The left CSS property specifies part of the position of positioned
>   elements.
>        For absolutely positioned elements (those with position: absolute or position: fixed), it specifies the distance between the left margin
>   edge of the element and the left edge of its containing block.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left

As the CSS `left` property is part of `position:*;` property's, fix by adding the position property, so jquery knows what to increment a left value to.

<kbd>**[In Action](http://jsfiddle.net/YrHyc/2/)**</kbd>

**CSS**

```
#headlineText
{
    margin:60px 80px;
}
#headline1Txt
{
    position:relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainContainer">

    <div id="headlineText">
        <p id="headline1Txt">Striped Bag</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#headline1Txt').
       animate({ 'marginLeft': "100px" }, 1000).
       animate({ left:"+=30" }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: You can also nest subsequent animations like for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gw3x8/

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

You want the text to slide in (heading right across the screen) then slide another 30px?

Thats what `$("#headline1Txt").animate({ 'marginLeft': "+=30" }, 500);` will achieve.
`'marginLeft'` not just `left`.

Answer (score 0):

The left property of css only works with elements with absolute position. To make your animation work you have to put you element at absolute position.